# How to manage config for different environments like dev prod uat when code deployed through Azure CI DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a Develop branch in VSTS and build(CI) definition is successful. Now, I want to deploy build to Dev and UAT and PROD environments. If release is success, then all environments will have Dev settings, since Dev build/Dev branch web.config have dev settings. How can I manage UAT/PROD/DEV settings for respective releases.

Note: Dev settings mentioned in web.config of Develop branch.

**Update 1:**

For below XML file, values need to be modified at runtime based on different environments.What need to be configured in Release pipeline for .xml file value changes.

```
<RPSServer>
 <Sites>
 <Site SiteName="default">
 <SiteId>123546</SiteId>
 <ReturnURL>Custome URL</ReturnURL>
 </Site>
 </Sites>
</RPSServer>
```

In above xml file, SiteId and ReturnURL will be different for DEV,UAT and PROD

Comment: Take the configuration out of the code/config and use the web app configuration (assuming that is how you host your application)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a release pipeline then using variables can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where did you deploy to, however both the [Azure App Service Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) and [IIS Web App Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops) tasks now support [file transforms and variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops). In case you are deploying the app through Azure App Service Deploy task, there is **File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options** that can do transform.

You can also use [XDT Transform extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform) that can apply transform for config file, so you can include/add the related configure files in release artifact, then configure transform per to release environments.

Another way is that you can replace the value in configure file through [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) or [Tokenization task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TotalALM.totalalm-tokenization).

You can reference the following blogs to do that:

- [Using Tokenization (Token Replacement) for Builds/Releases in
  vNext](https://dustinoprea.com/2016/05/06/using-tokenization-token-replacement-for-buildsreleases-in-tfs-2015/)
- [Tokenize your VSTS pipeline the easy way!](https://willys-cave.ghost.io/tokenize-your-vsts-build-the-easy-way/)
- [Manage Web.config Values between Environments in Release Management
  and TFS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2018/03/19/manage-web-config-values-between-environments-in-release-management-and-tfs/)

-

#### UPDATE:

It's also available to replace the tokens for *.xml files. For example with the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension, we can edit the xml file as below, then set variables for different environments/stages.

```
<RPSServer>
 <Sites>
 <Site SiteName="default">
 <SiteId>#{SiteId}#</SiteId>
 <ReturnURL>#{URL}#</ReturnURL>
 </Site>
 </Sites>
</RPSServer>
```

Reference below screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I also have an .xml file along with .config file where values needs to be changed for different environments at runtime.How can we do that. Looks like, File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options applicable only for .config files

Comment: @chandrasekhar It's also available for .xml file. I have posted an example with the Replace Token extension to do that, please see the updated answer.

Comment: @chandrasekhar Have you resolved the issue with the updated answer? Any update here?